# Why are there no naturality condition in definition of exponential in a category?

Tags: category-theory

In chapter 6 "Exponentials" of "Category Theory" Second Edition, Steve Awodey, 2010, there is no naturality requirement in the definition of exponential in a category.

Exponential is an adjoint and so must be natural, right? Why do I see no naturality requirement in the definition of exponential?

Comment: What's your definition of the exponential object? If it's an object $B^A$ together with a unique morphism, then the uniqueness of that morphism suffices to give you the naturality condition.

Comment: Awodey's formulation includes the $\epsilon$, which implies naturality.

Comment: Adjoints may be defined "objectwise" - naturality etc. comes for free, of course from the universal property (see Mac Lane's book).